# PowerPC assembler not recognizing undefined variable with @h annotation

Tags: assembly, powerpc, undefined-variable

If I assemble the following `PowerPC`...

`asm.as`:

```
li r0, hello
nop
```

... I get an appropriate error message:

```
> powerpc-eabi-as -mregnames -mgekko ../asm.as -o asm.ob 
../asm.as: Assembler messages:
../asm.as:2: Error: unsupported relocation against hello
```

This is because `hello` is undefined. The error is desired behavior. However, if I use the `@h` (higher 16-bits) annotation, it will silently assemble and assume `hello` has value `0`:

`asm.as`:

```
li r0, hello@h
nop
```

Commands used:

```
$ powerpc-eabi-as -mregnames -mgekko ../asm.as -o asm.ob 

$ powerpc-eabi-objcopy -O "binary" asm.ob asm 

$ rm asm.ob 

$ xxd -p asm 
3800000060000000
```

Why is this new code now accepted by the assembler when `hello` is still undefined? Is there a way to enable the error message again? I want to find out immediately if an undefined variable like this is used.

Comment: The first one isn't failing because `hello` is undefined. It's failing because without the `@h` you're trying to use the full address of `hello` as an immediate and it's too big.

Comment: Also, you're not getting the full story from `objcopy`. You should run `objdump -dr` on the object file to see the relocations. There will be one for `hello`, of a type matching `@h`, lined up with the place in the `li` instruction where the immediate goes.

Comment: As far as I know, assembly always allows you to reference an external symbol without declaring it. It becomes a relocation in the object file, and the linker applies the relocation to compute the final value that ends up in the executable. So there's no error to diagnose until you try to link, and fail to include a library or object file that defines `hello`.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: This was really useful and correct. How would you try to link to detect undefined variables then? I guess the code has to also mark an entry point and such to work but this shouldn't be required for this task

Comment: By linking into a static executable, obviously.   (Even if that's not your intended use).  e.g. This will make a static ELF executable: `powerpc-eabi-as -o foo  hello.o`, assuming it works the same as regular `ld` on my x86 desktop.

Comment: If you're trying to do something that actually ends with `objcopy` from an object file producing a useful executable with references resolved, then you're way outside anything I know how to do.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Use `nm -u` to find undefined symbols.

Comment: @fuz: Yes, that works fine. Thank you. This solves it pretty much even though the output is a bit strange

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza The output makes more sense when you compare it to the `nm` output without `-u`. Also try the `-P` option to get machine readable output. Read the man page and the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nm.html) for details.